# What does it meant " assignment of paper with decision in prosess " in the same time?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, rejection

I have submitted the paper to [JFA journal](https://ees.elsevier.com/jfa/default.asp) after the stage "submitted to the journal" (14 days ) ,I have received the message that paper is assigned with current stage " Decision in process " in the same time , Is this can say anything about acceptenece or reject of my paper ?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the editorial board is in the process of making the final decision about your paper.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but my question is to know anything about acceptenece or rejectness of my paper , but i feel it will be reject since rarely journal accept paper within this short time

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Being in final stages of making the decision means a decision has not been made yet. So, you cannot conclude anything from this status and you have to be patient and stay positive.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your paper had status 'submitted to journal' for 14 days and then jumped immediately to 'decision in process'. In principle this means the editorial board is making a decision - possibly the assigned editor has already made a recommendation, and now it just remains for the editor-in-chief to make the final decision.

However this would also indicate that the paper skipped the peer review stage entirely. This is not a good sign I'm afraid. Either your paper is so groundbreaking that its correctness is self-evident (leading to an immediate accept decision) or it's being editorially rejected.

EDIT: There's something else that looks pretty possible - a revise decision because the editors can't understand your English. They might also say reject and resubmit.

Comment: your answer convince me, it's stay to send to you my paper and give me then your opinion if it is possible just to share me your Email, probably my english is not good

Comment: @zeraouliarafik what do you want me to do though? If you want to improve your paper's English, you'd need to approach a professional editor, e.g. Enago, Cactus, etc - Google for "professional english editing".

Comment: Thanks ,just to check the paper and to say me if it will suitable for publication .